# Split strings from registered event output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have just started working with `IO.FIleSystemWatcher`. My current code works and alerts me of created files in the desired location, however I want to pipe some of the variables out and split the strings. I cannot get the split portion to work.

Functional Code:

```
$folder = 'D:\Output'
$filter = '*.jpg'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
Out-File D:\Output\scans\$name.txt    
}
```

`$name` will always be formatted like so 'file.name.fn_xxx.jpg' and I want to use `split` to pull 'file' from `$name`, for example:

```
$name.split('.')[0]
```

However, this does nothing as far as I can tell. For instance I can output a file with `$name` as the filename, but if I try to split it first nothing outputs.

Non-Functional Code:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green

$name = $name.split('.')[0]    
Out-File D:\Output\scans\$name.txt    
}
```

This is a bit over my head so any advice or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Bill_Stewart they are using the `.Split()` method, not the regex operator.

Comment: I'd try adding in a `Write-Host $name.gettype()` and make sure that `$name` is a string, and not an object. If it isn't a string try `$name.tostring().split('.')[0]`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician using gettype identifies it as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working it out by simply using another variable.

```
$folder = 'D:\Output'
$filter = '*.jpg'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
Write-Host "$name"

$x = $name.split(".")[0]
Out-File D:\Output\scans\$x.txt
```

I am not sure why this works, but it does. If anyone knows why please comment!